# Auto-Typecasting Java class to a Boolean

Tags: java

I'm attempting to solve somewhat of an odd "issue". I have a class that I am using to describe error types. It stores an ID, a name, and a short description. I want to be able to evaluate the class as a Boolean, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so.

Example:

```
public ErrType exampleFunction() {
    // ErrType(ID, name, description)
    // An int value of "1" is equivlent to true, anything else would be false.
    return new ErrType(1, "NO_ERROR", "No error occured");
}

public void testFunction() {
    ErrType err = exampleFunction();
    if(!err) {
        // Error thrown. Do something.
    } else {
        // No error thrown.
    }
}
```

I've tried something similar to the toString() method, but that did not work for obvious reasons.

toString() example:

```
class ErrType {
   ... code here ...

   public String toString() {
       return error_id + ": " + error_name;
   }
}

... more code here ...

ErrType err = new ErrType(1, "test");
System.out.println(err);
```

Comment: I feel like this is a XY Problem.  Is there a reason you need it to evaluate as a Boolean rather than just doing a null check and/or `Optional<ErrType>`'s `isPresent()`?

Comment: maybe add an `isError()` method to `ErrType`; or just `if (err.getID() == 1)`, assuming that method is implemented

Comment: It’s not a good idea for a method to indicate an error status in a returned value.  Developers usually don’t bother to check returned values (which caused a tremendous number of problems in C programs for many years).  The best way to indicate an error is to have ErrType extend Exception, then declare exampleFunction as `public void exampleFunction() throws ErrType`.  Now it’s easy for calling code to discern whether an error occurred:  any code which is not in the `catch` block can safely assume there was no error.

Answer (score 1):

In developing *Java*, they decided against this type of evaluation for *data-types*, due to the plethora of errors it created in similar languages, e.g., *C*, *C++*, etc.
It's sometimes referred to as *"parity"*.

The simplest solution is to just create a *method*.

```java
class X {
    boolean is() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
X x = new X();
if (x.is()) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create an evaluate function in the ErrType class like this;

```
class ErrType {
   ... code here ...

   public Boolean evaluate() {
       return this.error_name == "NO_ERROR";
   }
}
```

Then the main code would just be changing !err with !err.evaluate() like this;

```
public ErrType exampleFunction() {
    // ErrType(ID, name, description)
    // An int value of "1" is equivlent to true, anything else would be false.
    return new ErrType(1, "NO_ERROR", "No error occured");
}

public void testFunction() {
    ErrType err = exampleFunction();
    if(!err.evaluate()) {
        // Error thrown. Do something.
    } else {
        // No error thrown.
    }
}
```

Comment: detail: never use `==` to compare *content* of object (unless you really want to check if it is the same instance, not just equal content) - see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/85421) || in the code as posted, `==` will work since only using `literals`, but that is an edge case